# Scala: how to force type to be provided

Tags: scala, type-inference, scala-generics

Lets say we have the following trait and class definition

```
trait Model extends Product
class X[T <: Model] {}
```

Give the above I can create instance of X as follows.

```
val x = new X
```

The compiler does not complain. The inferred type in this case is `Nothing`. I would like to know how can I prevent this at compile time so that it is not allowed to create instances of X without providing an explicit type i.e is a subtype of `Model`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

```
trait Model
case class M() extends Model // one subclass of Model, for testing

// use implicit to force T to be convertible to Model
// which works for actual Model subclasses but not Nothing
class X[T<:Model](implicit f: (T) => Model)

new X
  error: type mismatch;
  found   : <:<[Nothing,Nothing]
  required: T => Model

new X[M] // ok
```

However you can still explicitly gives `Nothing` as type-arg (strange...):

```
new X[Nothing] // ok
```

---

I would go for the above, but an other idea is to explicitly pass as parameter the *class of the Model subclass*:

```
class X[T<:Model](tClass: Class[T])

new X(classOf[M]) // ok

new X(classOf[Nothing])
  error: type mismatch;
  found   : Class[Nothing](classOf[scala.Nothing])
  required: Class[T]
  Note: Nothing <: T, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T.
  You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: T`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

Answer (score 2):

`class X[T <: Model] {}` class definition means `T` type has *upper bound* as `Model` type. And `Nothing` is *subtype* for all the rest of the types. Thats the reason *Scala compiler* is not complaining.

Make the type `T` of `class X` a *contravarient* as

```
class X[-T <: Model] {}
```

so that when you define

```
val x = new X
```

it is treated by Scala compiler as

```
x: X[Model] = X@7c9bdee9
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not sure it does what the OP expect: `new X` makes a `X[Model]`

Comment: @Juh_ isn't that what the OP is looking for?

Comment: I think he wants the type to be given explicitly, i.e. that you cannot write `new X`

Comment: Yes not what I want, but I like the idea, so up voting.